# Servidor IIS no reconoce método PATCH en Net Core C#

Tags: c#, api, swagger

Tengo un Api en C# con un método PATCH que al ejecutarlo funciona normal (Swagger), el problema es cuando lo despliego en el server, es como si no reconociera la ruta. Sólo me ocurre con el PATCH (Get y Post funcionan bien)

[image: Error al ejecutar método PATCH]

Comment: Verifica la ruta. Verifica la llamada al server, a veces mandan POSTs o PUTs y se esperaba PATCH.

Comment: hola Mario, bienvenido, Hola xx, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, gracias, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.